# Where does the word trait comes from?

Tags: c++

I understand that C++ Traits are compile time properties that can be used to take some compile time choices for templates, but where does they come from ?

Can anyone point out some basic background material about the concepts behind traits ?

Where does the word traits come from ?

**EDIT**: I guess I should refine the question. I know of "character trait" (or "trait de caractère" in French for Philipp), but who thought about applying it to software ingeeneering to describe some kind of properties, and does it have the specific meaning I attach to it "compile time property" ?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=trait

Comment: It comes from French :-)

Comment: @Philipp: There goes the French trying to steal yet another word. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ Type traits by John Maddock and Steve Cleary
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/type_traits/c++_type_traits.htm

Traits: a new and useful template technique by Nathan C. Myers:
http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html

very helpful!
Matthew

Comment: I should check if Nathan Myers is the first user of the word, if so this is probably the right answer.

Answer (score 8):

It's a common English word. For example, a "character trait" is a property of a person, and could have values like "meanness", "kindness" or "patience".